# Ecommerce tracking checkout process with multiple users and google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

We have a site that resembles a ecommerce site in the checkout process.

We have users that add products to a "cart" but then they need to have the cart "approved" by another user before they can proceed with the checkout.

We have four checkout steps like:

1. Add products to the cart (user 1)
2. Send the cart for review (user 1)
3. Someone approved the cart (user 2)
4. Purchase the cart (user 1)

The problem is that that analytics seems to loose the checkout process in step 3. Is there some way that I can tell GA that all these actions belongs to the same process? I want to track the checkout process as one even if it consists of multiple sessions.

I track the steps like:

Step 1

```
// Track step 1 performed by user 1
ga('ec:addProduct', trackingObject);
ga('ec:setAction', 'add', trackingObject);
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 1
});
ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'action1', trackingObject.id);
```

Step 2

```
//Track step 2 performed by user 1
ga('ec:addProduct', trackingObject);
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 2
});
ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'action2', trackingObject.id);
```

Step 3

```
// Track step 3 performed by user 2
ga('ec:addProduct', trackingObject);
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 3
});
ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'action3', trackingObject.id);
```

Step 4

```
//Track step 4 by user 1
ga('ec:addProduct', trackingObject);

var purchaseTrackingObject = {
    'id': '<transactionid>',
    'revenue': trackingObject.price
};

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', purchaseTrackingObject);
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': 4
});
ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'purchase', trackingObject.id);
```

Comment: Where does user2 come in ? If he has to approve this in his own browser or device then it is no wonder that GA loses the checkout, since he will have his own cookie and client id and so will generate a session on his own. You might be able to make creative use of the user id feature and session unification (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en).

Comment: Yes, user 2 will have his own userid and session. I could make them have the same "userid" but that would mess up a lot of other tracking stuff. The best would have been if I could set a unique id for the checkout process. In the purchase step I can set a transaction id. I guess it not possible to set this id the the checkout starts?